# Read POP3 Email Account with SQL Server 2008

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, email, pop3

How can I read an accounts emails subject and content, and store these in my SQL Server database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need an application that connects to the POP3 account and retrieves the email.  Once you have the emails, your application can then pick out whatever information you need and then populate your SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Curt,

depending on whether you're able to 'programatically' extract the email body and header, you may want to look at some thing like: http://www.emailarchitect.net/ (look at the EAGetMail POP3 & IMAP4 COMPONENT 2.7) one for example.

I have no affiliations here, just have used this to good effect.